# PMON Registration

Tags: oracle

Understood from the documentation that in dynamic registration PMON will register the handler with Listener. Listener will handover the client request to the handler which in turn performs the authentication (also exchange the port to be used )and serve the request.

My Question is what will happen in case of static registration? Will PMON register the handler or Listener identified the database process using SID and retrieve the handler from it?

Answer (score 1):

Static registration is performed by editing `listener.ora` and adding the corresponding `SID_LIST_LISTENER` entries. That alone does not prevent `PMON` or `LREG` from dynamically register services in the listener.

Dynamic registration can be disabled by setting the `DYNAMIC_REGISTRATION_LISTENER` to `off`. With this setting, `PMON` or `LREG` will still try to register, but the listener will simply not accept these requests.

Comment: My Question is how listener identify the database process in case of static registration and how it handover the connection.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of static registration, listener will be unaware of the status of the instance. Is the database instance is off or on, listener  will not know. 
If you see listener status it will say

> Instance "PLSExtProc", status `UNKNOWN`, has 1 handler(s) for this service

Here `unknown` means this is a static registration. This kind of registration will also handover the connection with `SID_LIST_LISTENER` entries given in `listener.ora` file.This`listener.ora` file also have the information which listener connects with which database service (ex: `orcl`).It will just not know the current status. It is like a blind man on a train. He doesn't know whats going on. But in the end of the day he reaches his destination.